# Debug mode on Nexus 4 with a broken MicroUSB port?

Tags: usb, android, root

I broke the MicroUSB port of my Nexus 4. It works correctly when charging but not with the debug. I need to know how to enable the debugging over the Wi-Fi connection knowing that I cannot use in any way the usb connection.

The phone has a stock image without the root access.

Comment: What sort of debugging are you looking to do? adb over wifi? perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2605411/2813274) can help

Comment: It won't work. I'd need to run before `adb tcpip 5555` with the cable attached in order to do after `adb connect ipaddress:port`. And I cannot use the usb cable anymore.